# What is the difference between these two python codes using `input`?

Tags: python

```
a=int(input("Unesi a:  "))
b=int(input("Unesi b:  "))
c=a+b
print(c)
```

I do not understand what the difference is because it does the same thing.

```
d=input("Unesi c:  ")
e=input("Unesi d:  ")
f=int(d)+int(e)
print(f)
```

Comment: `int(20)` is the same as `20` just like `test = 7` and `test = 1 + 2*3` are the same. Different code does not necessarily mean different behavior.

Comment: Hint: Try inputting something that isn't a valid integer at each `input` prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both code snippets ultimately do the same thing, provided that the input is valid for `a` `b` `d` and `e`. If the input is not a number, `a` and `b` will give you a `ValueError` right away, since you're evaluating the string input to an `int` immediately. `d` and `e` will accept any sort of input, including those with non numerical data, but you'll get the same `ValueError` when doing the addition. Same result, different timing when errors occur.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comments (thank you again), I should also mention that if non-numeric input is given to `a`, you'll get a `ValueError` before ever getting to `b = int(input("Unesi b:  "))`. If non-numeric input is given to `d`, execution will happily continue on to `e` since you haven't cast the input to an `int` yet. Very subtle difference.

Comment: It's not quite the same result: if you give invalid input at the `"Unesi a:  "` prompt you won't see the `"Unesi b:  "`prompt. Whereas if you  give  invalid input at the `"Unesi c:  "` prompt you _will_ be shown the  `"Unesi d:  "` prompt.

Comment: Do you see any case where the second would be preferable? I think it's better to check the type as soon as possible, but I might be missing a situation.

Comment: @PM2Ring Good observation. I didn't really make that clear in my answer - thanks.

Comment: @Rightleg: I agree that the 1st form is preferable because if you're going to fail it's better to fail as soon as possible. However, the OP's question is simply to ascertain the difference in the behaviour of the 2 code snippets, not to evaluate which one is better.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, that's not my point, it just got me to wonder if there was some situations in which the second would be preferable. Actually I think that it's better for custom error management, but it's far beyond OP's question.

Comment: @PM2Ring Though, I doubt someone will ever come across a question whose title is "Can someone tell me the difference between these two python codes? I'm having a test in 2 hours, any help is appreciated", with "Python" for sole tag.

Comment: @Rightleg 1. For proper error management, you'd be catching the ValueError exception, and so it's still better to do the `int` conversions on separate lines. 2. Fair call. Please feel free to edit the question title. I presume the OP won't mind. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Great idea! Edited for the sake of help and clarity. Wooo

Answer (score 0):

The difference between these two is pretty subtle.  In the first case, when `a` and `b` are assigned, the inputs are collected, then cast to integers. If the inputs cannot be cast to ints at this time, an error will be thrown.

In the second case, there should be no problem assigning `d` or `e`, but an error will be thrown when you try to assign `int(d) + int(e)` to the variable `f` because `int(d)` won't make sense.